# How to uncheck closest header checkbox in jquery - multiheader in multirows with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

How to uncheck closest header checkbox in jquery. There are multiple headers in different rows, checkbox in header needs to be unchecked when all the child checkboxes are unticked.

Header checkbox is in class 'jq_idtHeaderEdit' and child checkboxes are in class 'jq_border_label'.

1- On child checkbox change event, how to check if all the child checkboxes in class 'jq_border_label' are unticked?

2- If all the child checkboxes are unticked then untick the header in closest class 'jq_idtHeaderEdit'.

Thats how the table looks like;

```
        <tbody>

        <tr class="jq_idtHeaderRow"></tr>
        <tr class="jq_idtListRow"></tr>
        <tr class="jq_idtHeaderRow"></tr>
        <tr class="jq_idtListRow">
            <td class="jq_idtContentEdit" valign="top" colspan="6">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="jq_idtContentEdit"></td>
                            <td class="jq_idtContentEdit"></td>
                            <td class="jq_idtContentEdit"></td>
                        </tr>
```

**Expanded table**

```
            <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainer_tabDetails_idtDiscipline_tblEdit">

            <tbody>
                <tr class="jq_idtHeaderRow"></tr>
                <tr class="jq_idtListRow"></tr>
                <tr class="jq_idtHeaderRow"></tr>
                <td class="jq_idtHeaderEdit" colspan="6">

                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainer_tabDetails_idtDiscipline_ctl24" type="checkbox" value="160" checked="checked" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabDetails$idtDiscipline$ctl24"></input>
                    <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainer_tabDetails_idtDiscipline_ctl24"></label>

                </td>
                <tr class="jq_idtListRow">
                    <td class="jq_idtContentEdit" valign="top" colspan="6">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="jq_idtContentEdit">
                                        <div class="jq_border_label_container">
                                            <div class="border_label_box">
                                                <span class="jq_border_label" style="background-color: whitesmoke; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"
                                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabContainer_tabDetails_idtDiscipline_ctl32" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tabContainer$tabDetails$idtDiscipline$ctl32" checked="checked" value="197" type="checkbox">
```

[image]

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/m1Lmg616/6/

I want Header-2 to be unticked when all his child checkboxes are unticked.

I have tried this in 'onchange' event of child checkbox but no luck so far;

```
var jqo = $(this);
if ($(jqo).closest('.jq_border_label').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked').length > 0) {
        alert('at least one ticked');
    }
```

Comment: please post a fiddle for this.

Comment: You can definitely use JQuery's selectors to do it, but I think it would be much easier to maintain if you add a unique id element to the headers and associate the rows with each header.  That would keep the logic intact even if the table structure changes somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.chkChildHeader').on('change', function () {
        var checkedNum = $('.jq_border_label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        if (checkedNum > 0) {
            $(this).closest('.jq_idtHeaderEdit').find('.chkBoxHeader').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.jq_idtHeaderEdit').find('.chkBoxHeader').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

> I have prepared the following sample demo and below is the js fiddle link:
>   https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/41v9s4vv/15/

I think you can use this as reference to solve your problem since you didn't provide fiddle to your problem..

Fiddle shows that even if only one checkbox is checked,header checkbox is checkbox and  if none of the child checkboxes are checked ,header checkbox is unticked.

If you want to checkbox only if all the child checkboxes are checked, then below is the code you can use

```
$('.chkChildHeader').on('change', function () {
        var length = $('.jq_border_label > input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var checkedNum = $('.jq_border_label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

        if (length === checkedNum) {
            $(this).closest('.jq_idtHeaderEdit').find('.chkBoxHeader').prop('checked', true);
        }
        if (!checkedNum) {
            $(this).closest('.jq_idtHeaderEdit').find('.chkBoxHeader').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

and below is the fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/1ecqs3bu/1/